# Qt radiobutton color change

Tags: qt

I'm trying to change the dot's color of the radiobutton using the following code:

```
ui->radioButton->setStyleSheet("QRadioButton{ color: red;}");
```

in Linux it's working like a charm but on windows it's just changing the label color of the radiobutton
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

For changing dot's color of QRadioButton use QRadioButton::indicator :

```
ui->radioButton->setStyleSheet("QRadioButton{ color: red;} QRadioButton::indicator{color : blue;}");
```

most complete example from qt docs:

```
QRadioButton::indicator {
      width: 13px;
      height: 13px;
  }

  QRadioButton::indicator::unchecked {
      image: url(:/images/radiobutton_unchecked.png);
  }

  QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked:hover {
      image: url(:/images/radiobutton_unchecked_hover.png);
  }

  QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked:pressed {
      image: url(:/images/radiobutton_unchecked_pressed.png);
  }

  QRadioButton::indicator::checked {
      image: url(:/images/radiobutton_checked.png);
  }

  QRadioButton::indicator:checked:hover {
      image: url(:/images/radiobutton_checked_hover.png);
  }

  QRadioButton::indicator:checked:pressed {
      image: url(:/images/radiobutton_checked_pressed.png);
  }
```